# Kotlin equivalent of AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

AsyncTask is dead (deprecated)

So what structure do I use to replace my [AsyncTask.SerialExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask#serial_executor)? I've made the dive into coroutines and channels, but there's nothing I've come across that can serially queue a series of requests and ensure they execute in turn with no concurrency. Nothing that isn't a) already deprecated (like actor) or b) experimental (not something I want to touch with a production build).

Maybe I'm missing something in how CoroutineScope is defined? Some little trick with channels?

Comment: Use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to get an `Executor` with a single thread. Either then use that directly, or use [the `asCoroutineDispatcher()` extension function](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/java.util.concurrent.-executor/as-coroutine-dispatcher.html) to wrap it in a `CoroutineDispatcher` that you would use in place of things like `Dispatchers.IO`.

Comment: Thank-you @CommonsWare. This is I believe should do the trick as long as there's no `delay()` or `suspend fun...` calls within the request blocks. My understanding is that since threads != coroutines, if a coroutine hits a point where it is suspended, it will switch to the next coroutine that can still run. I originally tested with delay(...) calls and it seems this is what was happening. Once I took these calls out, the blocks ran sequentially

Comment: You are correct @mienko, using a single thread stops concurrency (multithreading) but does not assure sequencial execution of tasks, interleaving can still happen. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#fan-in for reading from a channel from a single coroutine.

Comment: Thanks @nickallen. I see you commented in the Kotlin forum as well. Using a channel would be great for guaranteeing sequential execution but my understanding is there's no way to return a response using channels. The solution using the single thread executor allows for a block with a returnable value, so i can write code like this: `val onMainThread = apiInterface.sequentialRequest()`. Am I right in my understanding that channels can't do this?